# How can I save 'access_token' from url in localstorage in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, local-storage, query-string

How do I write access_token from url in localstorage in the `$onInit` method in angularjs es6? When I look at the development tools in the Application -> localstorage tab, `token` is assigned the value `undefined`.

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

class AppController {
    constructor($window, $location) {
        'ngInject'
        this.$window = $window;
        this.$location = $location;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this.$window.localStorage['token'] = 
            this.$location.search().access_token;
    } 

}

export default AppController;
```

Comment: Try using the AngularJS `$location` provider (you'll have to inject it). Then you can simply save the value from `$location.search().access_token`.

Comment: `$location.search().access_token`  return token. But I can't set 'token' in localStorage

Comment: Have you tried injecting `$window` and then using `$window.localStorage['token'] = $location.search().access_token`? I encourage you to use the AngularJS version of things - it will make your life much easier.

Comment: It does not work. When I am in the Application-> localstorage tab. When I refresh the page for a moment I see token, in a moment  I see 'undefined' again. I updated question

Comment: Use the Developer Console to put a breakpoint in the `$onInit` function. Examine the data at that point.